# Java and Stanford Parser

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I used StanfordCoreNLP jar file library to split English paragraphs into sentences but I could retrieve the split sentences as CoreMap Object, but I want to convert those split sentences of type CoreMap to type String, is there anyway to achieve this task. The bold text in the code shows the area where CoreMap is used and I want the sentences retrieved to convert it to String

The code snippet:

```
    props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize,ssplit");
    //put that in a pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    //a data structure for the annotation
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run the pipeline on that data structure
    pipeline.annotate(document);

    // access the annotations which has worked on a sentence 
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/sakshi/Desktop/Admin_System/translate.en"));
    PrintStream console = System.out; // To store the reference to default output stream to use it to restore the default std output stream
    System.setOut(printStream);// To change the default output stream
    **for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        System.out.println(sentence);**

    }
    System.setOut(console);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write(text);
```

Comment: Welcome, please see [ask] and show us what you have tried and on what you are stuck. Preferably using a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`whatever.toString()`
since toString works for every java Object since every object inherits from java.lang.Object

Comment: If the implementation of the `CoreMap` interface include a `toString`. Or `Object.toString` will be used and this won't help ! And why do you try to cast the `String` into a `CoreMap` ?

Comment: The Stanford API uses CoreMap for retrieving the split sentences(as an example on Stanford's webasite), that is why I used it  and I am not that proficient with Java

Comment: @moneydhaze Check the user name !! And of course, [**be nice**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Actually I am working with machine translation system and in order to translate a user given paragraph (source text to be translated), initially I want to split the paragraph into separate sentences and then send these sentences one by one to the machine translation software to be translated, but for that I need the sentence to be in string format before sending the source text to the translation software

Comment: Use this to validate the solution [Example 2](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap). At least it would be "documented".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about exact types of the CoreMap, but probably Map#values() is a List that you need. To convert it into the single String you could use Java8 Streams API:

```
list.stream ().map (i -> i.toString ()).collect (Collectors.joining (","));
```